# Complexity of |= in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time-complexity

What is the complexity (Big O), for this operation:

`my_array |= [new_element]`

Is it `O(n)` because it needs to go through the existing array checking if `new_element` exists?

Comment: Yes, use "toogle code" option from documentation - http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C and you will see there are two loops iterating through the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand upon Wand Maker's comment.
Take a look at

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-7C
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c

Source for `rb_ary_or`

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_or(VALUE ary1, VALUE ary2)
{
    VALUE hash, ary3;
    long i;

    ary2 = to_ary(ary2);
    hash = ary_make_hash(ary1);

    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary2); i++) {
        VALUE elt = RARRAY_AREF(ary2, i);
        if (!st_update(RHASH_TBL_RAW(hash), (st_data_t)elt, ary_hash_orset, (st_data_t)elt)) {
            RB_OBJ_WRITTEN(hash, Qundef, elt);
        }
    }
    ary3 = rb_hash_values(hash);
    ary_recycle_hash(hash);
    return ary3;
}
```

I would say that the answer to your question is "yes" (at best -- refer to @cliffordheath's comment)", as it seems we have O(n1) for `ary_make_hash(aryl)` and O(n2) for the `for` cycle.

Comment: ary_make_hash is not O(n), because the hash has a (small) logarithmic element, which contributes an O(n*log(n)) to the overall

Comment: Instead, my point is that I should refer to what I referred to.
However, I find such a discussion so pointless that I am going to respect your opinionated pro-forma observation.